# How to view each and every column in a mysql table in a pop-up-window by clicking view in PHP?

Tags: php

I have listed a table from the database in the web page with 'edit,delete,view' option in each and every column. Now how can i view a particular column in a apop up window (for eg - a student detail) by clicking view ???

Comment: use bootstrap model http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: I dont have any code. I'm just a beginner. I've created a table named " students " using phpmyadmin. The task given to me is "Student Management Application". Only Principal and staff could login. Principal can view add delete edit the datas of both teacher and students. But the staff after login could only view the list of students of the standard to whom he handles. PRINCIPAL, when he clicks view (present in each and every column) a pop up window should appear which contains the details of that particular student or staff.

Comment: Do your own homework, your suppose to learn from it.

Comment: I will also learn from your answer sir. Right now i have improved myself to a stage of understanding a php code. Can you pls get me the code???

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap for open popup in modal window. Check below URL http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: this is the task given to me.Student:
- Student Listing page along with filters : a) Student Name b) Class c) Teacher and d) Date of Birth.

- 
- On clicking "View" from the listing, Student information will be listed out though popup. Calculate the age based on Date of Birth and display it next to Date of Birth.
- On clicking "Delete" icon from the listing, you need to warn Principal about the deletion of Student record.
- In the listing page, you are going to have a link: "Add Student". On clicking upon it, Student form will be popped out.